# Appropinquaretur

Tags: sentence-translation, translation-explanation

The rarely observed imperfect-subjunctive-passive creates a knotty problem.

North & Hillard, Ex215: "Had we only kept to the main road, we should already be approaching the city."

This is an example of impossible (mixed) conditions: first part is in the past, requiring pluperf. subj. (tenuissemus); second part--present, requiring imperf. subj. (appropinquaremus).

Answer Book: "si modo certum iter tenuissemus, iam ad urbem appropinquaretur."

Despite the English simply requiring "appropinquaremus"--we-would-be-approaching; the imperf. pass. subj is deployed, in the singular--so it's not "we" anything! The city must be the singular element giving: now to the city 
it-would-be-being-approached.
How clumsy is this?
How is this to be written, in English, while retaining the purity of the imperf. subj. pass?

Answer (score 1):

A general warning:
A literal translation of a natural Latin expression is not always fluent English, and *vice versa*.
Beware of drawing conclusions on naturality by comparing two languages.

It would be perfectly valid to replace *appropinquaretur* by *appropinquaremus*.
Making such a replacement would indeed take the sentence closer to the English original.
The translation tells the same story, but it is not very literal — and there is nothing wrong with such translations.

What the answer key suggests is an impersonal passive; *ad urbem appropinquaretur* means more or less "the city would be approached".
The active version with *appropinquaremus* would mean "we would approach the city".
Notice that the city is not a subject and would not be the object in the corresponding active clause *ad urbem appropinquaremus*.
The passive clause is impersonal, but it is implicitly clear that a "we" should be understood.